# Recommendations for substituting CoreServiceClient with SessionAwareCoreServiceClient

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

The interfaces `ISessionAwareCoreService` and `ICoreService` are almost identical, `ISessionAwareCoreService` has couple of more methods than `ICoreService`.

It seems to me like `ISessionAwareCoreService` could easily inherit from `ICoreService`, but it does not. I guess there is a good reason behind it.

(Does anyone know why?)

Anyways, let's get to the topic. I'm creating an extension method for `ComponentData` as shown below:

```
public static SchemaData GetSchemaData(this ComponentData data, ICoreService client)
{
    return client.Read(data.Schema.IdRef, new ReadOptions(){}) as SchemaData;
}
```

The consumer of this class should inject the "client" object obviously, and it has to be type of `ICoreService`.

But what if the consumer is using `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure? If you look at the API, you will see that it does actually (note that these are the versioned interfaces)

[image]

The main difference between the two is that the session aware let's you work with sessions and has the ability to impersonate someone else. Also one important difference is that when using the `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient` you cannot use `BasicHttp` binding.

To answer your main question, the most primitive solution would be to overload the extension method :)

Comment: Hi  @Atila Sos, Thanks for the swift answer. Where is that "Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.dll" supposed to be? I have only  "Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll"


p.s:I actually typed a sentence like "please don't recommend overloading" but then removed it in the end.  lol!

Comment: Hm, now that you mention it, the `Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll` is indeed the right one, it contains the pre-built proxy classes, but I don't know recall their inheritance from the top of my head. However, if I think back hard enough, I do vaguely remember having a similar struggle as you have. I will have to check this and will update my answer accordingly afterwards .

Comment: The confusion here is that the Core Service API docs are generated from the server-side types. The client-side types are generated from the WSDL and the interface inheritance gets lost in that process.

Comment: Great point Rick - one to remember where looking at types, methods etc.

Comment: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-DEF8EB01-8807-4126-B51B-0A4D47C81AEE

Comment: Might it be possible to address this as a product issue? How much control do you have over the generation of the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering to create my own interface `Custom.ICoreService` that's inheriting from `Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService` and service clients inheriting from that custom interface as well as actual Tridion Core Service clients. It will allow me to pass 'Custom.ICoreService' objects around while preserving the exact same functionality as the actual clients.

```
public interface ICoreService : Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService
public class CoreServiceClient : Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceClient, ICoreService
public class SessionAwareCoreServiceClient : Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.SessionAwareCoreServiceClient, ICoreService
```

However, it doesn't feel right.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It would work, I guess. As a matter of fact, you don’t need to define your own (marker) interface. Just a subclass of SessionAwareCoreServiceClient which implements the standard ICoreService would do the job (?)